# Unabled to format USB Drive

Tags: release-juno, usb-drive, disk-management, filesystem

Neither `Gparted` nor `Gnome Disk Utility` let me format a USB Drive. I don't no when this started, because a few weeks ago everything worked just fine. Now `Gnome Disk Utility` just throws an error `Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)`.

If I use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` to clear out the drive I can format it, but then I appears to be owned by `root` and i can't change the permissions either.

Somebody got an idea how this comes or how to fix it?

---

**Update**

I still got the same problem and have tried nearly everything I could come up with or find elsewhere. If I plug in any usb drive it automounts, but i can't access it without `root` privileges. I tried to change the ownership with `chown`, but it only gives me `Operation not permitted` as an error.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this, might work (Gparted):

https://askubuntu.com/a/377396/890782

---

Also from Debian's launchpad report (link below)

> You can work around this bug in gnome-disk-utility using these steps:
>
> After selecting the SD card, instead of clicking the gear icon to format,
>     click the partition in the "Volumes" section.
>
> Delete the partition ("minus" icon)
>
> Create a new partition

Is a really old bug you have there

https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/util-linux/+bug/1059872

Answer (score 1):

There is an app on AppCenter, Formatter, which might become useful. Try this.

Comment: Already tried that, i seems like it's not an application specific problem, but rather a system wide.